# Assign range from a different workbook to variable

Tags: excel, vba, range

I want to use the WorksheetFunction.Match function, and need to load this with an area.

```
Row = WorksheetFunction.Match(country, Countries, 0)
```

Can you help me construct the Countries variable? 
I tried lots of ways (including the below) but none seem to work...

```
Countries = Workbooks("PERSONAL.XLSB").sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B") 
Countries = Worksheets("PERSONAL.XLSB!Sheet1").Range("B:B") 
Countries = Worksheets.Range("PERSONAL.XLSB.Sheet1!B:B")  ...
```

I also tried some of the above with "Set" in front but that didn't help either...

Comment: What happens when you try to run the code. Do you get an error message? Do you actually have a PERSONAL.XLSB workook? I'd try assigning the range to another workbook, one you can see. And you do need to use `Set` to assign a range. Your first example, with `Set` added, is the correct syntax.

Comment: If the solution below worked then accept the answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Well I used the code below and it works OK. You do have a PERSONAL.XLSB file which is loading and hidden when you start Excel? What is the error message - is it subscript out of range?

```
Public Sub test()

 Dim r As Integer
 Dim Countries As Range
 Dim Country As Range

 Set Countries = Workbooks("PERSONAL.XLSB").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C8")
 Set Country = Workbooks("PERSONAL.XLSB").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

 r = WorksheetFunction.Match(Country, Countries, 0)

 MsgBox (r)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

OK problem solved, thanx Dave!

I actually use it as a Function that returns the "area" to which the country belongs:

```
Function AreaEMEA(Country As String)
 Dim Countries As Range
 Dim Areas As Range
 Set Countries = Workbooks("PERSONAL.XLSB").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B")
 Set Areas = Workbooks("PERSONAL.XLSB").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
 Row = WorksheetFunction.Match(Country, Countries, 0)
 AreaEMEA = WorksheetFunction.Index(Areas, Row)
End Function
```

which i call using

```
"=PERSONAL.XLSB!Module1.areaemea(A1)"
```